# How to count occurrence(s) of each character in a string and encode output as [character] [number] [character] [number] format?

Tags: r

I want to count occurrence(s) of each character in the following string and output the result as [character] [number] [character] [number] format, lowercase and sort by the character.

```
"Hello World !"
 d 1 e 1 h 1 l 3 o 2 r 1 w 1 ! 1
```

Comment: `do.call(paste, as.data.frame(table(strsplit("Hello World !", ""))))`

Answer (score 0):

Solution in base R. First we split the string using strsplit() and empty string "" as split. Also unlist and sort at the same time. For good measure, we define a vector of strings we do not want in our output; it seems you don't count the space " " as a character. This has to be defined. Next, a little package pasted in paste0()'s. First, use lapply on the uniques of characters to count each occurance. Then, paste this with the respective string (and an equal sign). Last, collapse the resulting string with commas.

Here is the code:

```
example_string = "Hello World!"

unwanted_chars = c(" ")

split_string = sort(unlist(strsplit(example_string, "")))
split_string = split_string[split_string %in% unwanted_chars]

paste0(paste0(unique(split_string), " = ",
                                unlist(lapply(unique(split_string),
                                                        function(x) sum(x == unlist(split_string))))),
             collapse = ", ")
```

The long line looks a bit ugly, if you want to undestand it, unwrap it layer by layer.

Answer (score 0):

@Calbers is right that `strsplit` is the right way to go, but it can be achieved using a one-liner:

```
examples = c("Hello World!", "Lorem ipsum")
lapply(strsplit(examples, ""), table)
```

i.e. split each element of the `examples` using the null split `""` and then `lapply` the `table` function to it. With a single example it is:

```
table(strsplit(examples, "")[[1]])
```

i.e. we take the first element from the list outputted by `strsplit`.